# Deleting Related Records in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

Very new to Access and the existing answers on this site are too technical for me...

I would like to delete records in my Access database that are linked across multiple tables. How can I safely delete a record? Ideally, I would delete the record in one table and it would be removed from all related tables.

Thank you!

Comment: When creating/editing a relation between tables, you have two options in the _Enforce Referential Integrity_ section. One is "Cascade update". If ticked it will set all related fields to NULL when the row is deleted. You also have cascade delete that when ticked will cause all related rows to be deleted when the row is deleted. I think what you want can be achieved with Cascade delete.

Comment: litelite is bang on with his answer. This is the only way Access will programatically do it for you. You can access this by going to Database Tools > Relationships. From the table you want to delete the single record from, drag the field that relates to the other table and drop it on the key in the other table. Double click the line to bring up the dialog he is referring to, and select cascade delete. Do this for each related table.